# scons: overriding build options for one file

Tags: scons

Easy question but I don't know the answer.

Let's say I have a `scons` build where my `CCFLAGS` includes `-O1`. I have one file `needsOptimization.cpp` where I would like to override the `-O1` with `-O2` instead. How could I do this in scons?

---

**update**: this is what I ended up doing based on bialix's answer:

in my SConscript file:

```
Import('env');

env2 = env.Clone();
env2.Append(CCFLAGS=Split('-O2 --asm_listing'));

sourceFiles = ['main.cpp','pwm3phase.cpp'];
sourceFiles2 = ['serialencoder.cpp','uartTestObject.cpp'];
objectFiles = [];
objectFiles.append(env.Object(sourceFiles));
objectFiles.append(env2.Object(sourceFiles2));
   ...
```

previously this file was:

```
Import('env');

sourceFiles = ['main.cpp','pwm3phase.cpp','serialencoder.cpp','uartTestObject.cpp'];
objectFiles = env.Object(sourceFiles);
   ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Object() builder for fine-grained control over compilation, and then pass these objects to Program() builder.

E.g. instead of:

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(target='foo', source=['foo.cpp', 'bar.cpp', 'needsOptimisation.cpp'])
```

You need to use following:

```
env = Environment()
env_o1 = env.Clone()
env_o1.Append(CCFLAGS = '-O1')

env_o2 = env.Clone()
env_o2.Append(CCFLAGS = '-O2')

# extend these lists if needed
SRC_O1 = ['foo.cpp', 'bar.cpp']
SRC_O2 = ['needsOptimisation.cpp']

obj_o1 = [env_o1.Object(i) for i in SRC_O1]
obj_o2 = [env_o2.Object(i) for i in SRC_O2]

env.Program(target='foo', source=obj_o1+obj_o2)
```

You can avoid creation of separate clone of env variable if you provide CCFLAGS='-O2' right in the Object() call:

```
obj_o2 = [env.Object(i, CCFLAGS=env['CCFLAGS'] + ['-O2']) for i in SRC_O2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Avoiding creating of a separate env variable requires (ref: [bialix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2014424/119527)) needs something like this.

```
 obj_o2 = env.Object(SRC_O2, CCFLAGS=env['CCFLAGS'] + ['-O2']);
```

If you just do this (or in the for loop like bialix does)

```
 obj_o2 = env.Object(SRC_O2, CCFLAGS='-O2');
```

then you lose all the builtin flags.